# Passing different value for same parameter to @wire apex method in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components

I have an apex class with a parameter. I need to pass two different static values for that parameter through LWC. Shall I import the apex method twice using in JS file ?

APEX:

```
public class MyController{

    @AuraEnabled (cacheable = true)
    public static void myMethod(param){
           // some code here
    }
}
```

LWC JS file:

```
import myMethod from @salesforce/apex/MyController.myMethod

export default class MyLWC extends LightningElement{

   @wire myMethod({param : 'String'})
//for this param I need to pass two different string values. should I import the method twice or there is any other efficient way to do that
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify more on what actually are you looking for?

Comment: There is a parameter in apex class which I need to pass through JS in lwc. I have two value suppose 'String1' and 'String2' . Do I need to import the class twice to pass 2 values for the same parameter in apex ?

Comment: where you will store those two parameters in apex transaction? Are you talking about passing the values dynamically to the method?

Comment: Dude, understand that there is only one parameter in apex method which I am using but 2 static values that I need to pass to that parameter when I call it in LWC.. You can see the structure above.. there is no two parameters only one parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to call the method with two different parameter values at the same time. You don't have to import it twice, just call it twice and annotate different properties / functions:

```
import myMethod from @salesforce/apex/MyController.myMethod

export default class MyLWC extends LightningElement{

   @wire myMethod({param : 'String1'})
   property1;

   @wire myMethod({param : 'String2'})
   property2;
}
```

However, if you want to call the method with one value, and then with a different one (sequentially), you can use a dynamic variable instead:

```
export default class MyLWC extends LightningElement{
   value = 'String1';

   @wire myMethod({param : '$value'})
   property1;

   handleButtonClick() {
       this.value = 'String2';
   }
}
```

That way, the wire service will react to the parameter value change and provision a new return value (in my example, on a button click handler).

Comment: Thanks Alba....